# ConTeXt : Cross-referencing and setuphead

Tags: context

I tried some tweaking with the `\setuphead` command, in order to have the sections appear as I wanted. In particular, the subsection titles appear without the section number.

However, when I use `\in` to reference this subsection, I would like to see the whole number, like I.1 in the following MWE.

```
\setuppapersize[A4][A4]
\setuphead[section][sectionsegments=section, conversion=Romannumerals]
\setuphead[subsection][margin=1cm, sectionsegments=subsection, conversion=numbers]
\starttext
\section{One}
\subsection[sec:oneone]{One-one}
Text
\subsection{One-two}
Text
\section{Two}
\subsection{Two-one}
Text reference to one-one should be I.1 and it is only 1 : \in[sec:oneone]
\subsection{Two-two}
Text
\stoptext
```

In this achievable in ConTeXt ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is certainly achievable in context. The main problem with context is to find out how, as documentation is sparse and if you find example they seldom explain the underlying concepts. The following seems to work, but I have no idea why one has to use `sectionconversionset` instead of `conversion` (which doesn't give a roman numeral in the reference). I also don't understand the exact syntax of `prefixsegments`.

```
\definestructureconversionset [myset]
 [
   Romannumerals,
   Romannumerals,
   Romannumerals,
 ]
 [numbers]
\setuphead [sectionconversionset=myset]
\setuppapersize[A4][A4]
\setuphead[section][sectionsegments=section]
\setuphead[subsection][margin=1cm, sectionsegments=subsection]
\setupreferencestructureprefix [subsection][default] [prefixsegments=section:*]
\starttext
\section{One}
\subsection[sec:oneone]{One-one}
Text
\subsection{One-two}
Text
\section{Two}
\subsection{Two-one}
Text reference to one-one should be I.1 and it is only 1 : \in[sec:oneone]
\subsection{Two-two}
Text
\stoptext
```

[image]

### Side remark:

Imho it would be more context-like if you would use `\startsection` / `\stopsection`

Comment: I completely agree that the documentation is scarce and not very well organized. It would be great if a ConTeXt-guru could create a big tutorial for making a totally custom layout, with this kind of modifications, and deeply explained a concept at each part of the tutorial...

Comment: The conversions are explained in the [`\definestructureconversionset`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/definestructureconversionset) page.  The syntax for `prefixsegments` is `begin level:end level`, here `section:*` means »beginning from `section` all the way down«.